# Current Date and Time malfunction

Tags: javascript, date, time

I was wondering if anyone can see anything off in my code, I am pretty new at this and having a lot of trouble. This is for my class im taking.  Its supposed to say good morning/afternoon depending of time and display the time as well. heres the code;

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>"Welcome"</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        var dateObject = new Date();
        var greeting = " ";
        var curTime = " ";
        var minuteValue = dateObject.getMinutes();
        var hourValue = dateObject.getHours();
        if (minuteValue < 10)
            minuteValue = "0" + minuteValue;
        if (hourValue < 12) {
            greeting = "<p>Good morning! "
            curTime = hourValue + ":" + minuteValue + " AM";
        } else if (hourValue == 12) {
            greeting = "<p>Good afternoon!";
            curTime = hourValue + ":" + minuteValue + " PM";
        } else if (hourValue<17) {
            greeting = "<p>Good afternoon! "
            curTime = (hourValue-12) + ":" + minuteValue + " PM"
        } else {
            greeting = "<p>Good evening! "
            curTime = (hourValue-12) + ":" + minuteValue + " PM"
        }
        var dayArray = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
        var monthArray = new Array("January", "February"
                "March, "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", 
                "September", "October", "November", "December");
        var day = dateObject.getDay();
        var Month = dateObject.getMonth();
        document.write("<p>" + greeting + "It is" + curTime
                + "on" + dayArray[day] + "," + monthArray[month]
                + "" + dateObject.getDate() + ","
                + dateObject.getFullYear() + ".</p>");
        /* ]]> */
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <h1>Welcome to my Web page</h1>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

W3c Validator is confusing but says I have 2 warnings...

Error Line 43, Column 36: end tag for element "P" which is not open

```
     + dateObject.getFullYear() + ".</p>");
```

and

Line 48, Column 6: required attribute "ACTION" not specified

```
   <form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm missing a comma after "February", and a quote mark after March.

The variable `Month` should be `month` (lowercase m) to correspond with the subsequent code.

Then with `"It is "`, `" on "` and `", "` instead of `"It is"` `"on"` and `","` (add spaces) I'm getting the following result, which looks good:

> Good morning! It is 11:15 AM on Sunday, September 6, 2015.

Note that because you write to the document which already has a heading, the date appears **before** the header, which may or may not be what you want. You could add a span or div somewhere and write there, but that's beyond the scope of your question.

Does that fix it for you as well?

Comment: Hey thank you so much this did help!! However it works fine if i put the code in one of those W3C try it yourself windows .like in here; http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_myfirst but if i try to run it from my notepad++  to chrome it doesnt give me the button to click to display the current time..any ideas? I am supposed to put this on the website we're making for the class but once i put the javaScript in and test the page I do not see a section for this.

Comment: You're welcome! 
What you're asking is something else than in the original question, but add a button to the body 
`<button id="showDateButton" onclick="showDate()">What's the date?</button>
<span id="dateString"></span>` 

and then put this function in the javascript
     `function showDate() {
         document.getElementById('dateString').innerHTML = "<p>" + greeting + "It is " + curTime
                + " on " + dayArray[day] + ", " + monthArray[month]
                + " " + dateObject.getDate() + ", "
                + dateObject.getFullYear() + ".</p>";
    }`
Is that what you meant?

Comment: thank you so much for the code, this really helps!..  however for some reason the time does not populate after adding the info and clicking the button.

Comment: That's right - you may want to put the whole JS code in the function so it calculates the time at every button click, instead of just on loading the page.

Comment: oh i see awesome man!! thank you so much for your help - you just made my day!!!!! Have been so stressed with this class lately lol

Comment: hey man, I really hate to ask again... but im having difficult adding it in.  I was just going to leave it and get partial credit but i feel its something simple here. Im just not really sure how to do that if you can steer me in the right direction I'd appreciate it. It is an online class im taking and it hasnt been going tooo well...but I am trying to learn .  Thanks agian for your time today!

Comment: Sure, please be specific about what isn't working, what errors you are getting, what exactly you are trying to do and don't know how to...

Comment: the way to go about putting the javascript code into the function...im not too familiar with doing this.  I tried this at the end of the code. 
"September", "October", "November", "December");
var day = dateObject.getDay();
var month = dateObject.getMonth();
document.getElementById('dateString').innerHTML = 
document.write("<p>" + greeting + "It is " + curTime
 + " on " + dayArray[day] + " , " + monthArray[month]
 + "" + dateObject.getDate() + " , "
 + dateObject.getFullYear() + ".</p>");
 }

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the idea is to put all of the code between the `<script>` tags between the curly brackets of `function showDate(){ ... }`.